# Write huge xarray dataset physically reorganized by `MultiIndex` to disk

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray

When collapsing xarray dimensions into `MultiIndex`, merely the index is changed, leaving the underlying data as is.

This new data organisation can then be reflected in the underlying memory the data occupies by accessing `.values`, causing the data to be computed.

My dataset is too big, however, to be loaded into memory with `.values`. As such, I would like to write it to memory (preferably in Zarr format) by each chunk. I do not care about the underlying dimensions and only want to persist the `MultiIndex` as a 1D array.

Zarr does not support `MultiIndex`, unfortunately. The solution proposed by the error message, namely to use [cf_xarray.encode_multi_index_as_compress](https://cf-xarray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/cf_xarray.encode_multi_index_as_compress.html) makes the underlying dimensions reappear and it seems that when writing, the data will not be reorganised.

How do I proceed here?